# same header file in multiple source files in a c++ program

Tags: c++, header, g++

If the same header file is included in multiple source files in a c++ program , then how does it effect the compilation ( Especially **g++** ) ?

Will the compiler load the header file only once and compile it for every source file that includes the header or the header file will be loaded separately for every source file that includes it .

Comment: How header files are loaded is, AFAIK, not specified in the C++ compilation model. The implementation may choose to load it once, load it on demand (for every source files), or load it in some other bizarre way unimaginable by my finite brain.

Comment: basically `#include *.h` means "substitute" all the text from *.h file here

Comment: Conceptually each file you compile gets a fresh look at the header. In reality, there's a pretty fair chance your compiler supports some form of pre-compiled headers, so it compiles the source code to some intermediate form, then uses that when it compiles other files that include the same header.

Comment: Is there a chance that g++ compiler is optimized to load a header file only once even upon multiple calling from different source files ?Please confirm.

Comment: @biraj bora: It depends how you call `g++`. If you call the compiler each time you compile a C++ source file, it cannot make some caching from one instance to another (since a new process is spawned each time you compile a file). However the OS will probable cache the file itself...

Comment: @birajbora it absolutely could.  Precompiled headers are a common thing and don't have to be stored in memory in a single process.  They can easily be written to disk and used later by subsequent processes.

Answer (score 6):

Speaking to g++: `#include`s are done by the pre-processor, and not the compiler itself. You can see the result of pre-processing by using g++'s `-E` switch. (Edit: The pre-processor used to be separate but is now part of the compiler executable, however the pre-processing phase is still a distinct phase of the compilation process for the purposes of answering this question).

With gcc, clang, icc and msvc, each file is going to be visited every time it's encountered, even within the same source file.

The only case where this is not true is if the header file contains a `#pragma once` statement. Some compilers have a similar optimization for the user of include-guards:

```
#ifndef THIS_FILE_H
#define THIS_FILE_H 1
/* the stuff in thisfile.h */
#endif
```

There is a technique called "precompiled headers" supported by msvc and gcc (and probably clang) that will work with you to avoid the compilation head of a commonly used set of headers.

Typically this is done by having a .h or .cpp file with all your `#include`s in; you then `#include` this file first in each file (or use the idea of a 'forced include': /Fi in msvc, -include with gcc). Each file that uses a given pch has to have the same defines and compiler options.

If you were to write the following .h file

```
// bah.h
"bah",
```

and the following .cpp file

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* words[] = {
    "hello",
#include "bah.h"
    "world",
#include "bah.h"
#include "bah.h"
    NULL
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; words[i] != NULL; ++i ) {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output would be

```
hello
bah
world
bah
bah
```

Comment: It is not exactly true that "for `g++`: `#include`-s are done by the pre-processor": since many years, `g++` is starting `cc1plus`, which is a single program doing pre-processing, parsing, optimizations, code emissions.... The preprocessing is done by the compiler (`cc1plus`), not separately. (It was a separate process in GCC in the 1990s).

Comment: So far as I knew, the preprocessor was still a discrete pass completed in its entirety before beginning the compilation phase?

Comment: This was true long time ago... And is wrong today. `cc1plus`(from GCC 4.x) is linking an internal library `libcpp` which does the preprocessing and some tokenizing. And preprocessing happens during (just before the parsing) incrementally.... GCC does not work by preprocessing all at once, and later parsing the preprocessed form (even if it seems to work this way).

Answer (score 4):

Most header files have special protection against multiple includes like

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

// header body...

#endif MY_HEADER_H
```

Without this protection, header may be included more than once and this may cause compilation or linking errors.

Compiler may be smart enough to avoid reading file more than once. But, even if it did not, operating systems are very good at caching files which were recently read, and this will load very, very quickly - almost at no cost.

Comment: If you read the question, it is about including the header across multiple SOURCE files.  Not multiple includes in a single source file.  I'm pretty sure you didn't answer the question as asked, but instead a similar question with an entirely different answer.

Comment: @mvp : yes, recompilation is pretty fast in comparison to the first compilation of the codes.

Answer (score 2):

The ***pre-processor*** will **simply replace the macro definition in every source file**, and after that was done, the ***compiler*** will start to compile every source files to independent assembling files, which will then be translated to a binary machine code by ***Assembler***. And the ***linker*** will at last link all the object files to a single **executed file** or a **shared object**.

So it's basically non of the business of a compiler in a pre-processing progress. And g++ is a bundle of tools include pre-processor, compiler, linker.

Comment: If the compiler package will translate the same header file for every source file into the compiled code, then where is the code optimization happening ?

Comment: @birajbora In the compiling step. I don't think there are much work to do for the head file in optimization. After all, all those are declarations of functions or definitions of class or other information that need a uniform expression. You have all your functions declared in a header file, and another cc file for implementation. You don't want to implement your functions in a header file, do you? But when that does happen, I think they will be optimized during the compiling step independently but I am not sure.